# Best use of wondering if "there was something" or "something was"

Tags: questions, politeness

I would like to ask whether an object is included in a package or not, which of the following expressions should I use:

- I was wondering if there was any chassis support in the package?
- I was wondering if any chassis support was included in the package?

Can I use the present with `I am wondering if` + `there is` instead of the previous questions?

Comment: All of those are fine.

Comment: See also: [ell.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can and should use the present tense if you are referring to an item you have not yet purchased: "I was wondering if (object) is included in the package?"

Note that if the object is separate to another item, you have to use the singular definite or indefinite article: 'the' / 'a, an'

Example:

"I was wondering if a hammer is included in the package?" (you should use 'the' if the advertisement mentions or shows a hammer but doesn't state clearly if it's included in the price)

Your initial question indicates that you are referring to 'an object' named 'chassis support'. Is that the name of the object or are you asking if the object itself has support 'built in'?

If the item you're buying has chassis support 'built in' (or could have) then you must ask:

"I was wondering if the object includes chassis support?" or:
"I was wondering if the item comes with chassis support (or must I pay extra for this)?"

Comment: I've just learned @narutov6 that you have to ask this on the English Language Learners site...sorry! But no...you can't use the past tense to talk about the present! ('I was wondering' is past tense because it's something you stop doing at the point of asking but also just to make your question less direct/more polite). If you haven't bought it yet: use the present tense or you will confuse the sales advisor. Use one of my last examples or: "does/will the motor come with chassis support?".